# Ellipse / Circle Detection on Blastomere

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Can anyone give me advice on blastomere detection method?

I want detect multi ellipse / circle on blastomere in vitro fertilisation process. This image is very noisy. Can someone give me advice on which papers or methods I should explore? Thanks for advance.

[image: example1]
[image]

I had made experiment in this domain, but i didn't get good result because i am still confuse to validate ellipse so the final result contain false ellipse detection and valid ellipse. I used multiple ellipse detection based on arc segment for core method, and i preprocessed this image with adaptive threshold and morphological process. here i attach my experiment. I use c++ and opencv for my experiment.

[image]
[image]

I goal of my research is to detect ellipse in blastomere like this :

[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide manually created images having the expected correct segmentation?

Comment: can you make some assumptions (like: "there are always exactly 4 ellipses I want to detect")? I guess they are neither circles nor ellipses in reality - would be assuming ellipses still be ok?

Comment: Micka >> No we can't make assumptions that exactly 4 circle that will detect but the blastomere that will detect will be in the range 1 - 8. The shape sometimes not exactly circle or ellipse but it is okay to make approaching with ellipse or circle.

Answer (score 0):

May be this idea will help:

- get edges of assumed size (as I can cell edges thickness is more than 1 pixel, I am not sure adaptive threshold is the best solution in this case) using appropriate edge detector parameters,
- reduce noise using morphology operations,
- put one circle in every place and calculate warp-type-distance for this circle, use threshold for this distance to understand where edges seems like circle.

Sure it is calculation-intensive because it is multi-dimensional search for function min and dimensions are:

- edge thickness T -- +1
- morphology parameter W (size of window) -- +1 (or it could be function of T)
- X and Y position of circle -- +2
- circle radius R -- +1

So it is warp-distance-function minimum search in 4 or 5-dimensional parallelepiped, where only X and Y position gives ~50*50 = 2500 variants (T may give just 5 variants [1;4], W in [2;5] too, R can have exp steps like 100, 110, 121... etc), and wrap-distance calculation usually is not very fast. But at least this could be parallelized very good and also could be accelerated by GPU. I think it could be done in minutes, not hours. For small images even in seconds.

Comment: >> do you have paper refence or site reference that explain step 3 ("put one circle in every place and calculate warp-type-distance for this circle, use threshold for this distance to understand where edges seems like circle") .. because i can't imagine detail this step ... thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean 2d warping, it is like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping for 2D case. Google "2D warping".